# Specify data type when writing a GeoTIFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotools, opengis

I'm using `org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat` to write a GeoTIFF. I would like to use Float32 instead the default Float64. I've tried:

```
    OutputStream output = ...
    Hints hints = new Hints(Hints.SAMPLE_DIMENSION_TYPE, SampleDimensionType.REAL_32BITS);
    GridCoverageWriter targetWriter = new GeoTiffFormat().getWriter(output, hints);
```

But it still writes as Float64 (as verified with `gdalinfo`). Any ideas?

Comment: what are you writing out? is it a float or double based raster?